# Neo4J match and create relationship is very very slow with few millions records

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have about 3.5M nodes with label A and about 400 nodes with label B.

Nodes with label B already have directed relation like `(b1:B)-(c:CONNECTS)->(b2:B)` now I need to add 3.5M another type of relationships by comparing A node properties with `:CONNECTS` relationship properties.

My statement looks like this:

```
MATCH (a:A)
MATCH (c:C)
MATCH (b1:B {id: a.a1_id})-[rl:CONNECTS*1..21]->(b2:B {id: a.b2_id}) WHERE ALL(x in rl WHERE x.connect_id = c.connect_id)
MATCH (new_a:B)-[r:TO]->(new_b:B) WHERE r in rl
CREATE (new_a)-[:TICKET {ticket_id: ID(a)}]->(new_b)
```

This statement is extremely slow and just hangs up. I even tried to do some performance tuning mentioned [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-performance-tuning/), especially I allocated heap size to 16GB.

I find it quite strange that it can't handle this size of data. What am I missing? I tried to model differently and reduce relationship queries and use more schema index, but I failed to do a lot differently because of type of data I have and type of query I want to perform after all data is there.

I also tried to use periodic commit while creating A nodes with csv import. It has same issues.

I hope I am clear enough. I would really appreciate some inputs. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you do something like this?

Comment: Basically, A nodes are passenger tickets (with price, from stop and to stop) and B nodes are transport stops. B nodes are directed relation.

I need to find numbers of passengers between two stops called segment here http://i.stack.imgur.com/sRMa9.png  Thus, I need to know which tickets pass through two stops.

Comment: There may be a better way to approach things, but your description is not clear. For example: 1. What are `C` nodes for? 2. Did you mean for the `CREATE` clause to use `(new_a)` instead of `(new_b)` on the left?

Comment: c property is need to use with where clause. This is relational db schema I am trying to change to graph. I fixed tyo for new_a.

However, I am trying another approach where I use existing relation and add extra property instead of creating new relation. Looks like that will work and is a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

What are the labels A, B, C ? A CONNECTS relationship is also free of meaning.
Queries like this are meant to be comprehensible not the opposite!

```
// generates 3.5M rows
MATCH (a:A)
// generates x-times 3.5M rows
// you never use that C except for checking an connect id?
MATCH (c:C)
// many million times execute this variable length expand
MATCH (b1:B {id: a.a1_id})-[rl:CONNECTS*1..21]->(b2:B {id: b2_id}) 
WHERE ALL(x in rl WHERE x.connect_id = c.connect_id)
// lookup by relationship is very bad esp. as you looking over a cross product of all 400x400 B's
MATCH (new_a:B)-[r:TO]->(new_b:B) WHERE r in rl
// why do you store the id of a on this self!!-relationship?
CREATE (new_b)-[:TICKET {ticket_id: ID(a)}]->(new_b);
```

Where does b2_id come from?

Perhaps something like this:

```
MATCH (a:A)
MATCH (b1:B {id: a.a1_id})
MATCH (b2:B {id: {b2_id}})
MATCH (b1)-[rels:CONNECTS*..21]->(b2)
WHERE ALL(x in tail(rels) WHERE x.connect_id = head(rels).connect_id)
UNWIND rels AS r
WITH a,startNode(r) as new_a, endNode(r) as new_b
CREATE (new_a)-[:TICKET {ticket_id: ID(a)}]->(new_b);
```